# What is the difference between the Google App Script Scriptlets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm wondering what exactly is the difference concerning real world use cases between these 3 Google App Script Scriptlets to use them for HTML Templating:

Standard Scriptlet:     `<? .....?>`

Printing Scriptlet:     `<?= .....?>`

Force-printing Scriptlets:  `<?!= ... ?>`

The Google documentation is pretty cryptic saying that the second one is using Contextual escaping and the other 2 dont. But for what should you use which one. Can anyone give provide an example for each?

Thank you in advance

A

Comment: Try creating your own example

Comment: Or try testing the examples provided in the documentation.